# How to create a VB.NET COM-visible interface without IDispatch?

Tags: vb.net, com, idispatch

If I create a COM-visible VB.NET interface, such as:

```
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Sub MyMethod()
End Interface
```

Then the resulting type library will show `IMyInterface` inheriting `IDispatch`. Is there a way to inherit just `IUnknown`, and not `IDispatch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [InterfaceTypeAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.interfacetypeattribute) like this:

```
<ComVisible(True), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Sub MyMethod()
End Interface
```