# C# how to implement IDispatch Interface?

Tags: c#, idispatch

I have known that a class like blow will auto implement `IDispatch` interface:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Test
{
}
```

Now my need is to override the `Invoke` function, how can I do this?

Supplement:
I have a class `Test` and then I want to make a wrapper to make the `Test` seems has more function:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class TestWrapper
{
    public void NewFunc()
    {
    }
    private Test _test;
}
```

I cannot make `TestWrapper` to inherit from Test class, so I need override the `IDispatch.GetIDsOfNames` to expose test's interface. How can I do this?

Comment: I have try use `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]` and then make TestWrapper inherit from IDispatch`public class TestWrapper : IDispatch` and then override each interface of IDispatch, but it cannot work.

Comment: `ComVisible` by default  implements `IDispatch` unless you use `InterfaceTypeAttribute` with `InterfaceIsIUnknown` see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/66634482/14868997

Answer (score 0):

`ComVisible` by default implements `IDispatch` anyway, unless you use `InterfaceTypeAttribute` with `InterfaceIsIUnknown`.

So there is no need for anything special to get `IDispatch` functionality.